# Как можно склеить два байта?

Tags: битовые-операции, c++

Пример:
1011 + 1001 = 10111001

UPD: ошибся с примером, конечно же вот так 00001011 + 00001001 = 0000101100001001

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
unsigned char a = …;
unsigned char b = …;
unsigned int result = (a << 8) | b;
```

Comment: в ответе falstaf складываются "байты" то есть 2х 8-мь битов

а у @worialhat в примере складываются половины байтов то есть 2х 4 бита

    unsigned char a = 11;//1011 
    unsigned char b =  9;//1001 
    unsigned int result = (a << 4) | b;

Comment: Пример в вопросе, конечно, заголовку не соответствует. Остается только гадать, что именно хочет узнать ТС.

Интересно, а такой пример 

    1010000 + 100 = 1010000100

тоже подходит под понятие "склеить два байта"?

Comment: да, ошибся, именно так как вы сказали и хотел сделать,
но передумал и первый ответ мне вполне подходит

Answer (score -1):

```
 unsigned char  a = ...;
 unsigned char  b = ...;
 unsigned short c = ((unsigned short)a << 8) | b;
```